# Setting width of relative-line-numbers

Tags: line-numbers

I am using the relative-line-numbers-mode and a 90 degree turned screen, which makes the text jump when it goes from displaying 100 in the relative number.

Is it possible to set a fixed width for the line numbers, i just need it set to 3 characters.

Answer (score 7):

You can customize how to display the number. For example, define the following function that formats numbers as `003:`:

```
(defun jp-rel-format (offset)
  "Another formatting function"
  (format "%03d: " (abs offset)))
```

Then customize the variable `relative-line-numbers-format` to use this new function instead of the default `relative-line-numbers-default-format`.

You may try other format strings such as "%3d" to avoid leading zeros.

However, I just installed `relative-line-numbers-mode` and I don't experience the jump with numbers beyond 100. Are you using variable pitch font?