# How to set relative line-number digit width?

Tags: org-mode, line-numbers

I have set my number line relative to cursor as such:

```
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)
```

But, In a long file with line-difference more than 4digit (1000+), change in 3digit to 4digit makes my text jump when I move around. ( https://asciinema.org/a/gCKoaT7DymQoDiFklHBKJHBgC ).

[This answer 7years](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13192/setting-width-of-relative-line-numbers), suggests to customize `relative-line-numbers-format` variable. But I don't know how.

how change set relative line number 4-digit, or whatever-many-digit?

Comment: I don't think there is a `relative-line-numbers-format ` variable any longer (at least I can't find it after loading `display-line-numbers`). But do `C-h v display-line-numbers-width` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following, command removes the issue by setting the width longer.

```
(setq display-line-numbers-width 4)
```

This only works in a current buffer, I still couldn't figure it to make globally change it.

Added to my keybindings, so that I use it each time opening big org-files.